# JSON в массив JS

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, post

Имеется такой JSON:

```
[
{
    "id":4,
    "name":"aaaaa",
    "parentForumId":0
},
{
    "id":9,
    "name":"Технический раздел",
    "parentForumId":0
},
{
    "id":10,
    "name":"Технический раздел",
    "parentForumId":0,
},
{
    "id":11,
    "name":"Технический раздел",
    "parentForumId":0,
}
]
```

Как преобразовать его в многомерный массив? Что бы можно было пройтись по нему и брать данные из него, что то вроде date[s].id, date[s].name и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var response = `[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "aaaaa",
    "parentForumId": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Технический раздел",
    "parentForumId": 0
  }
]`;
var data = JSON.parse(response);
for (var s = 0; s < data.length; s++) {
  console.log(data[s].id, data[s].name);
}
```

Comment: Это понятно, мой вопрос в том, как преобразовать json ( из ajax запроса ) в js массив

Comment: @JigglyDezar `JSON.parse`

Comment: Уже пробовал, Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @JigglyDezar Пробовали неправильно.

Comment: `complete: function (data) {

                    var res = JSON.parse(data);
                    for (var s = 0; s < res.length; s++) {
                        alert(res[s].id, res[s].name);
                    }

                }`

Comment: @JigglyDezar `complete: function (data) { console.log(data); }` - ?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: @JigglyDezar `data` - это объект, а не строка. Что это за объект?

Comment: Igor правильно ответил, это вы уже нет отправляете ответ с сервера в ваш js.

Comment: responseText: `"[{"id":2,"name":"Технический раздел","parentForumId":1,"parentSubForumId":0,"messageCount":0,"topicCount":13678,"fontIcon":"fa-comments fa","userPermissionSubForum":null,"subSubForum":null,"topics":null,"heHasNonViewdTopic":false,"lastMessage":null,"isIgnore":false},{"id":5,"name":"ada","parentForumId":1,"parentSubForumId":0,"messageCount":0,"topicCount":1,"fontIcon":"fa-comments fa","userPermissionSubForum":null,"subSubForum":null,"topics":null,"heHasNonViewdTopic":false,"lastMessage":null,"isIgnore":false},{ ... "isIgnore":false}]"`

Comment: Решил проблемы вот таким колхозным способом -  `var res = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).responseText);`

Comment: @JigglyDezar `JSON.parse(data.responseText);`